# php function get default value if null is passed

Tags: php, laravel, function, default-value

I'm currently passing a value - which might be null - to a function that has a default value for that parameter. I expected that if the parameter is null, it would return the default value. But that does not seem to be the case.
Now I was wondering if there is a way to work around this?

I know I can check if the value is null, and don't pass it when it is, but I don't want to have too many if's in my code. I just want a clean way to grab the default value if it's null.

**Some extra info**: I'm using Laravel framework 8 - maybe some nice functions in Laravel I don't know yet.

Example [code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/771e9d4d446dcc07c5cb224e7778d5c19ff365e5):

```
<?php

class Person {
    private $name;
    
    public function greet(string $greeting = 'Hello')
    {
        return sprintf('%s %s', $greeting, $this->name);
    }
    
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}

$externalInput = null;

$person = (new Person())->setName('Maik');
echo $person->greet($externalInput);
```

This is just an example code, so don't mind the security issues this might have. That's all taken care off in my real code. This code is just to illustrate the problem I'm having.

Comment: You mean you would like `$person->greet(null)` to give the same result as `$person->greet()` & `$person->greet('Hello')`?

Comment: Just override the parameter if it is null: `if ($greeting === null) ....`

Comment: @ZoliSzabó That's exactly what I want ;)

Comment: @wayneOS I don't want that, so I'm looking for a different way, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: `null` is not the same as omitting an argument with a default value, so no, you cannot do it at language level. See @Bart's answer below. That's the closest you can get.

Comment: @ZoliSzabó is there a way to omit the parameter if the parameter is `null`?

Comment: @Refilon no, you have to NOT send `null`

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a ternary operator inside greet function like -

```
public function greet($greeting = null) {
   $greeting = isset($greeting) ? $greeting : 'Hello';
   return sprintf('%s %s', $greeting, $this->name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Same answer as the others, but a bit shorter (using the Null coalescing operator):

```
public function greet(?string $greeting = null)
{
    return sprintf('%s %s', $greeting ?? 'Hello', $this->name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
public function greet(string $greeting = null){
      return sprintf('%s %s', ($greeting ?: 'Hello') , $this->name);
}
```

Comment: I know I can do it like this, but that's not what I want. I was looking for a different way to do it, but by the looks of the comments there is not way to do it like this. So I will create some extra setters in my class and let those handle it. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do what you want to do. I understand your question but `NULL`, at least in PHP, is a relatively common and valid value that might be passed around, so it will be treated as a proper value, not as a missing parameter. I gave it a go by `unset()`tting `$externalInput` but that gave an expected undefined variable result.

Looking at your comments you probably already know this but the solution is to just do the 'old way', before default param values in PHP were a thing. If `0` or `''` are not valid values either, you can make it even nicer by swapping `$greeting === null` with `!$greeting`. Note that I've made the `$greeting` param a nullable string by adding `?`.

```
    public function greet(?string $greeting = null)
    {
        if ($greeting === null) {
            $greeting = 'Hello';
        }
        return sprintf('%s %s', $greeting, $this->name);
    }
```

Edit:: [Named arguments, new in PHP](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-named-arguments) could be a nicer solution as well. Seems like you can pass a splatted array `myFunc(...$arr)` as long as the key=>vals are paramName=>paramVal pairs. Then you could just filter the entire array and remove all NULL values in one go, rather than needing one of these `if(isNull)` for each individual argument.